# Using HashMap in greedDAO table model

Tags: java, android, sqlite, greendao

I need to create a database using greenDAO. In the table model, there is the  field:

```
HashMap<String, Map.Entry<String, ?>> flavours
```

By "?" hides an array of 1-5 Double elements.

When compiling, I get an error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:greendao'.
>
> > Can't add property 'Variable(type=VariableType(name=java.util.HashMap, isPrimitive=false,
> >     originalName=HashMap>,
> >     typeArguments=[VariableType(name=String, isPrimitive=false,
> >     originalName=String, typeArguments=null),
> >     VariableType(name=java.util.Map.Entry, isPrimitive=false,
> >     originalName=Map.Entry,
> >     typeArguments=[VariableType(name=String, isPrimitive=false,
> >     originalName=String, typeArguments=null), VariableType(name=?,
> >     isPrimitive=false, originalName=?, typeArguments=null)])]),
> >     name=flavours)' to entity PurchaseModel due to: **Unsupported type
> >     java.util.HashMap**

Found the information that for custom types it is necessary to make your own converter, but I have no idea what I need to do for my HashMap.

Maybe anyone know where to find an example of converting a HashMap into a format suitable for the database?

Comment: lists are allowed in Hashmap. Maybe you can try creating 2 lists - one for keys, one for their corresponding values ?

Comment: @KunalChawla Unfortunately, this did not help. "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:greendao'.
> Can't add property 'Variable(type=VariableType(name=java.util.List, isPrimitive=false, originalName=List<String>, typeArguments=[VariableType(name=String, isPrimitive=false, originalName=String, typeArguments=null)]), name=strings)' to entity PurchaseModel due to: Unsupported type java.util.List"